# compare two data set and update row if record found match

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

i have two data sets :

**Data Set 1** : ds1

```
        **Year            Period          Allowed**
         2012               1 
         2013               2
         2014               3
         2015               5
```

**Data Set 2** : ds2

```
       **Year            Period**     
         2012               1 
         2012               2
         2014               3
         2014               5
```

**Desired Data set :**

```
         **Year            Period          Allowed**
         2012               1                0
         2013               2                1
         2014               3                0
         2015               5                1
```

i want to compare both data set rows (year and Period) one by one and if record found same 
then add value "0" of column(Allowed) of first data set (i.e **ds1**)

**Note:** year and period of first data set must be same with year and period of second data set

Here is my code:

```
 for (int ds = 0; ds < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; ds++)
       {            
         string year = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[ds]["YEAR"].ToString();
         string per = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[ds]["PER"].ToString();

 for (int count = 0; count < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; count++)
        {
      string year1 = dsAllwedUser.Tables[0].Rows[count]["YEAR"].ToString();
      string per1 = dsAllwedUser.Tables[0].Rows[count]["PER"].ToString();
          if (year == year1 && per == per1)
                  {
                     row["Allowed"] = "0";
                     ds1.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
                      row.SetModified();
                  }
            else
                {
                    row["Allowed"] = "1";
                    ds1.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
                    row.SetModified();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Correct me if i am wrong ...thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good way for compare a dataset with another dataset is to use [DataTable.Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netcore-3.1).

```
private static DataSet GetAllowdDataSet(DataSet ds1, DataSet ds2)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("YEAR");
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("PER");
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("ALLOWED");
    DataRow[] dr = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string year = Convert.ToString(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["YEAR"]);
        string per = Convert.ToString(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PER"]);
        dr = ds2.Tables[0].Select(string.Format(" YEAR = '{0}' AND PER = '{1}'", year, per));
        if (dr.Count() > 0)
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new String[] { year, per, "0" });
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new String[] { year, per, "1" });
        }
    }

    return ds;
}
```